# How do you make this basic cube demo rotate at a constant speed?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, 3d, webgl, three.js

I'm beginning to learn Three.js. How do you rotate the cube in [this demo](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html) at a constant speed instead of rotating it with the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
plane.rotation.y = cube.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - cube.rotation.y ) * 0.05;
```

try something like:

```
plane.rotation.y = cube.rotation.y += ROTATION_STEP;
```

By `ROTATION_STEP` you can control the speed and direction of cube's rotation.

Comment: Aaah I see. So basically, the animate() function gets called recursively all the meanwhile the different parameters are altered. It's interesting because the framerate will depend on how fast the system can recursively call the animate() function. It looks like the framerate is onloy limited by how fast your system can call render().